# Export large document library from one Liferay 6.1 instance to another

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, portlet, document-library

I have one instance of Liferay 6.1 that has a large amount of files in its document library (the "data" folder zipped has almost 5 GB in size and the "document_library" folder has around 40 GB in size). I need to migrate the document library (including custom document types and custom metadata) from one Liferay instance to another.

The first thing i tried was to use the standard "Export / Import" command that is available at the Document Library control painel. The export process starts (i can see this by the loading indicator in my browser window) but it never ends to the point where i´am able to download a .LAR file.

In the last try i waited 6 hours to see if the server could complete the operation, but it didn´t work.

The server from where i want to export the data is Liferay 6.1.30 EE GA 3 running on Linux Red Hat with Tomcat 7 and uses Microsoft SQL Server 2008 as database. I need to migrate the entire document library (including custom document types and custom metadata) to a Liferay 6.1.2 CE GA 3 runnig on Tomcat 7 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (it is a development machine).

I´m almost trying to simply copy the folders "data" and "document_library" from one server to another, but i guess that doing this will not migrate the custom document types and custom metadata (i suppose they are stored in the database on some tables that include at least DLFileEntryMetaData and DLFileEntryType).

Can you give me some tips and ideas to acomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather not move such large amount of data through LAR files.

It is common to migrate this volume of data (for example, from a staging environment to production) but it is generally done by importing the database dump and copying the `data` directory. LAR files are basically ZIP files with all information you requested. Just imagine how long it will take to zip 30 GB! After that, you will have to download it, and even Tomcat may need some tuning to such a heavy download.

This sounds as a reasonable solution to your scenario since you are importing it into a development machine.

---

Nonetheless, that may not be always the situation - you may already have a working environment and only the Document Library should be exported. In this case, the solution, sadly, is to wait for the generated LAR file. If it is too unnerving, an option is to generate many LAR files selecting date ranges, so the exporting time will be smaller, possible errors do not cancel all exporting and you will check the evolution:

[image: The "Date Range" option allows the exporting of only part of data]

(I know, exporting such a huge file makes anyone anxious. Fortunately there is new feedback features on the exporting process in Liferay 6.2)

Comment: I already have a working environment and only the Document Library should be exported, this is exactly my case. I will try to generate many LAR files selecting date ranges, and see if it work. I will let you know and accept your answer if this works. Thanks. And about the new feedback features on the exporting process... wel... i´m working on 6.1 =(